# Running a validation rule on sql result

Tags: mysql

Requesting your help here.

1. I am trying to find a user_id who’s “work” activity hour range contains the input start_ts and end_ts.
2. Identified users (minimum Start time of the day +(Add) 1 hour) and  (Maximum End time of the day –(subtract) 1 hour) should not interfere the input “work” Start_ts and End_ts.

**For Eg:**
**Input:**

- **activity_name**="work"
- **start_ts** = '2023-01-02 13:00:00'
- **end_ts** = '2023-01-02 13:30:00'

**Expected output from below table:**

**| richjay | Work    | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 16:00:00.0 |**

- For richjay Minimum start time is 10:00 and maximum end time is 19:30 for the date.
- Adding one hour to minimum start time 10:00 + 1 = 11:00
- Subtracting one hour to maximum end time 19:30 – 1 = 18:30
- After doing addition and subtraction, the input start time(13:00) and end time(13:30) falls under the calculated time range 11:00 <- (13:00-13:30)  ->18:30
- Chris “work” activity 13:00 – 14:30 cannot be considered as adding one hour to his minimum start time(12:30 + 1) is interfering to the input start time.

**I tried the below queries:**

```
 SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILE WHERE activity_name="work" and (start_ts <= '2023-01-02 13:00:00') AND (end_ts >= '2023-01-02 13:30:00');

Result: 
| richjay | Work    | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 16:00:00.0 |
| chris   | Work     | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 14:30:00.0 |

Expected: only richjay should be displayed.

Tried this but it did not workout, I am new to sql please guide how to get the expected result.
SELECT * from
(
 SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILE WHERE activity_name="work" and (start_ts <= '2023-01-02 13:00:00') AND (end_ts >= '2023-01-02 13:30:00')
) AS SUBQUERY where group by user_id  having (ADDTIME(min(start_ts), '1:00') < ('2023-01-02 13:00:00')) and (SUBTIME(max(end_ts), '1:00') > ('2023-01-02 13:30:00'));
```

**Sample USER_PROFILE Table**

| user_id | activity_name | start_ts | end_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| richjay | break | 2023-01-02 10:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 10:30:00.0 |
| richjay | break | 2023-01-02 10:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 11:00:00.0 |
| richjay | Meeting | 2023-01-02 11:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00.0 |
| richjay | Work | 2023-01-02 12:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 12:30:00.0 |
| richjay | Work | 2023-01-02 12:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 |
| richjay | Work | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 16:00:00.0 |
| richjay | Meeting | 2023-01-02 16:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 16:30:00.0 |
| richjay | Break | 2023-01-02 16:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 17:30:00.0 |
| richjay | Break | 2023-01-02 17:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 19:30:00.0 |
| chris | break | 2023-01-02 12:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 |
| chris | Work | 2023-01-02 13:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 14:30:00.0 |
| chris | Meeting | 2023-01-02 14:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 15:00:00.0 |
| chris | Work | 2023-01-02 15:00:00.0 | 2023-01-02 18:30:00.0 |
| chris | Break | 2023-01-02 18:30:00.0 | 2023-01-02 19:00:00.0 |

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL ?

Comment: See my blog for efficient "range" tests something like yours:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Comment: Currently testing in MySQL, later will make changes to use it in Oracle